# Swift 4 how to know delete key is pressed when UITextField becomes first responder?

Tags: uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I've searched for the answer, it's all about using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function of UITextFieldDelegate. It works for most cases. But what if UITextField is already empty,`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method is not called any more when click delete button. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using multiple methods(not straight though!). One is to put an invisible button over it, or by subclassing `UITextField` and adding it as a custom class of the desired textfield. Then *override* the method `deleteBackward`. This method will catch all the backspace events.

**Subclass UITextField**:

```
// MyTextField.swift

import UIKit

protocol MyTextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidDelete()
}

class MyTextField: UITextField {

    var myDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate?

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        myDelegate?.textFieldDidDelete()
    }

}
```

**Implementation:**

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MyTextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // initialize textField
        let input = MyTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 150, height: 40))

        // set viewController as "myDelegate"
        input.myDelegate = self

        // add textField to view
        view.addSubview(input)

        // focus the text field
        input.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidDelete() {
        print("delete")
    }

}
```

Comment: @[chinmayan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5628642/chinmayan) Thanks. It works. I should be sorry for asking this question. I found a answer similar to yours, but I don't know why I ignored it. I'll be more patient to search and try before asking.

Comment: @Ryan.Yuen sure :-) please be patient while searching for an answer next time. May be the verfied answer won't fit into your requirement, but other answers will, go through them too :-)